# Modifying ESP32 code to serve image from memory instead of SPIFFS file

Tags: image, webserver, esp32, bmp

I am a barely adequate C programmer with no knowledge of HTML. I am trying to modify some code that reads a thermal image from a MLX90640. The code does everything I want but writes the image to a file in the ESP32 SPIFFS using a BMP format and then posts this to the webserver using the ESPAsyncWebServer library and the command below:

`server.on("/thermal", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){ request->send(PSRamFS, "/thermal.bmp", "image/bmp", false);});`

Using SPIFFS this way is going to wearout the SPIFFS flash memory in short order so I am trying to store and serve the image from ram.

The image was written to SPIFFS using writes like this:

```
file.printf("%c", blue);
```

I changed this to write to char image like this:

```
image[imageIndex] = blue;imageIndex++;
```

I verified that the changes produce the same byte array however reading the file back seems to bring back ints that are 0xffffffffffffffxx. I am wondering if this is the problem.

I changed the server.on code to this:

```
server.on("/thermal", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
request->send(200,"image/bmp",image);});
```

But I get a page with everything but an empty box where the image goes.

There is HTML code that is written to the client but I can't figure out how to post it here w/o it screwing up the post. The best I can do is point to the HTML can be found in the code at:

// GitHub: https://github.com/Samox1/ESP_Thermal_Camera_WebServer

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kurt

Comment: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/issues/303#issuecomment-439618991

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but here is my solution!

```
server.on("/capture", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
  }
  else{
    request->send_P(200,"image/jpg",fb->buf,fb->len);
  }
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
});
```

Basically, instead of using request->send(), you can use request->send_P() and directly send the frame buffer from memory to the client, no SPIFFS involved.

Answer (score 0):

send_P uses PROGMEM, i.e. program's flash memory. You're going to wear out your flash quickly.